# Hibernate query throwing ERROR:expecting "end", found '+' Unexpected token: end

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following query but its throw following error:

```
FROM Tbloans WHERE paidamt - (case when due=lastdue then dueamt else dueamt+nxtduedt end)>1
```

It gives me an error like this:

> expecting "end", found '+' Unexpected token: end

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` & `where` not works together you can use as following..

```
WHERE (due =  lastdue and paidamt - dueamt > 1)
   OR (due <> lastdue and paidamt - (dueamt + nxtduedt) > 1)
```